# copying all files from android to microSD

Tags: backup

- Phone = moto g
- OS = Android 4.4.4

I was going to back up all files on phone to microSD card using EZ file explorer. However, I have been reading that latest 4.4 will not allow this due to new security.

- Is it possible to copy all files from phone internal to external micro SD?
- Will this capture People, Chats, Photos, etc and be restore-able?

Comment: Hover the android tag for important info

Answer (score 0):

- if you have rooted your device, of course it is possible. application data lies in /data, also backup your /storage/emulated/0 I think
- if you have rooted the device, then you could also boot up a custom recovery like twrp and do a nandroid backup, afterwards move it to the external sdcard
- if you don't have rooted the device you only backup your internal sdcard. this also means that you may loose very much
- if you don't have rooted the device, there is also the possibility of using `adb backup` from a pc.